# Mailer Error PHP

Tags: phpmailer

i have created a PHP feedback form for my website. but it got error when i click the button submit. It said that "Could not instantiate mail function. Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.". I have tried many time for solving this problem.

My server is Windows server which is i am using PARALLEL HELM.

My Website link  with feedback form is  http://vivalife.com.my/home/index.php/contact-us/feedback-form/

I hope that anyone can solve my problem.

Thank you

Comment: Would you bother to show us the code?

Comment: doubt your hosting provider has disabled mail functionality

Answer (score 0):

I suppose phpmailer is an external class... And it's trying to use the PHP mail function. First of all check that your server has mail() function enabled.
To do so, I recommend doing something like this, on a php test file:

```
if (!mail(......)){
  // show error for debugging.
}
```

If [Mail Function - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is enabled, you should check the SMTP configuration on your php.ini file...

Let us know.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but, where can i enable that the mail() funtion ?? is it in on control panel or somewhere files??